# using class vs using function with ndb.model? google app engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I saw some examples that use function instead of class to declare ndb model:

declaring model with function:

```
def Person(ndb.model):
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    surname = ndb.StringProperty()
    languages_spoken = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, choices=languages)
```

declaring model with class:

```
class Person(ndb.model):
        first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
        surname = ndb.StringProperty()
        languages_spoken = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, choices=languages)
```

what is the difference between them ?

Comment: Where did you see examples using a function? It's valid python code, but it isn't a valid way of making an NDB model, and won't do anything useful.

Comment: Agreed. The first with the `def` looks like nonsense to me, so context would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to post a model with a function. The app engine doesn't allow for that. Ndb creates models as classes of Python, not as functions, so the examples you found are actually wrong.

This is to add to Greg and dyoo who just said it in comments. I want it posted as an answer.  Also interesting is to look at the [ndb examples from google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/), and in no case is it declared as a def.